# Too many arguments to ''

Tags: vb.net

> Error: Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Function Create(branch As Branch) As Branch

My code: Branch.vb

```
...
Inherits Resources

Private Const Path As String = "branches"
...

Public Shared Function Create(branch As Branch) As Branch
    Return Create(branch, Path)   'Path is underlined with error
End Function
```

And my Resources.vb file:

```
Public Shared Function Create(Of T As {Resources, New})(resource As T, path As String) As T
    Dim request = CreateRequest(path, Method.POST)
    request.AddBody(resource)
    Dim client = CreateClient()
    Dim responce = client.Execute(Of T)(request)

    If responce.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.Created Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Create Failed: " & Convert.ToString(responce.StatusCode))
    End If

    Return responce.Data
End Function
```

Now In my Resources file It used 2 values in header and in my branch.vb I specify 2 values, but still I have an error? What could this be?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `Return Resources.Create(branch, Path)`?  The `Create` method in your Resources file is a different method then the `Create` in your Branch.vb file - since you specified `Create` the compiler is going to use the `Create` in that file (class), in this case `Branch.vb`.

Comment: Your signature of Create looks like it takes only one argument, you are passing two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is you seem to think that `Shared` methods are inheritable (which they aren't). So given you are in the context of `Branch` when you call `Create` it assumes you are recursively calling `Branch.Create`, not `Resources.Create`.

You need to make sure you explicitly choose which `Create` call you want to call e.g.

```
Public Shared Function Create(branch As Branch) As Branch
    Return Resources.Create(branch, Path) 
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining and know what I was thinking.